# ASP.NET Redirect Url only if there is somthing after /

Tags: asp.net, regex, url-rewriting

I have this url : http://my_url.fr/

I want to redirect to http://my_url.fr/app_offline.html if peoples writes somthing after the url.

EX :

`http://my_url.fr/page/creation.aspx` redirect to `http://my_url.fr/app_offline.html`

`http://my_url.fr/test.aspx` redirect to `http://my_url.fr/app_offline.html`

There is my rewrite rule of the web.config :

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="asp_to_aspx" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="MATCH" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://my_url.fr/app_offline.html" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

What can I set insted of MATCH to redirect all path after the .fr ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match anything after host, use

```
<match url=".*" />
```